# Deleting a record with AJAX in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts in my Rails 3 app to allow users to create and save annotations to charts (which I'm saving with a dedicated scatterplot series with labels). I've been able to figure out how to save records to the database, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<%= service_annotations_path.to_s %>.json",
    data: {
      annotation: {
        name: name,
        time: new Date(x),
        value: y,
      }
    },
    success: function(msg){
      alert(msg);
    }
});
```

But I'm struggling to figure out how to implement the delete with AJAX. The problem seems to be two-fold:

1. I need to find the annotation record using the x/y coordinates for the selected point retrieved via JS from the chart, but I'm not sure how to pass this to this back to the controller/helper. I thought something like:

   ```
   var annId = "<%= find_annotation(this.x, this.y) %>";
   ```

   ... might work, returning an annotation id which I could use to delete the object, but I'm not sure how to access those JS coordinate variables [this.x and this.y] in Ruby from JavaScript... what I'm reading suggests it isn't typically done. (And examples I've found for circumventing that appear to have been deprecated.)
2. Then, I need to figure out the actual delete AJAX...

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: "DELETE",
       url: '<%= service_annotations_path.to_s %>' +  '/' + this.id + '.json',
       data: {
         annotation: {
           time: new Date(this.x),
           value: this.y,
         }
       },
       success: function(msg){
         alert(msg);
       }
   });
   ```

   Which itself is complicated by the fact that it's nested under the service resource.

I think if I can get the first part worked out, passing the x and y params from JS to Ruby should be doable. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Highchart provides various events for series's point.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events

You can get point's x and y using

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            console.log(this);
                            alert ('X: '+ this.x +', Y: '+ this.y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Hardik! I guess I shoulda mentioned that this part I've got figured out - I can get the point coordinates from JS (and even pass them to Ruby via POST). It's the whole delete operation (passing this.x/y to Ruby to find and delete the corresponding record) thats got me stumped.